# Where add .THIS to active only one li

Tags: javascript

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.arrow-toggle.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down').click(function () {
            $('.glyphicon-menu-down').toggleClass('up');
            $('.ul-unactive').toggleClass('ul-active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where add .THIS to active only one `ul`.
need help on blured one.

I tried this but `ul-active` didn't work:

```
$('.arrow-toggle.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.closest('.glyphicon-menu-down').toggleClass('up')
    $this.closest('.ul-unactive').toggleClass('ul-active')
})
```

When I delete `$this.closest` it work but all `ul`s are activated

html:

```
<li>
                      {% if gn.Nodes -%}
                          <span class="menu-toggle"><a href="{{gn.Url}}" class="">{{ gn.Name }}</a> <span class="arrow-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></span> 
                      {% else %}
                          <a href="{{gn.Url}}">{{ gn.Name }}</a>
                      {% endif %}

                      {% if gn.Nodes -%}
                          <ul class="ul-unactive">
                          {% for gnn in gn.Nodes -%}
                              <li>{{ gnn | A }} </li>
                          {% endfor -%}    
                          </ul>
                      {% endif -%}
                  </li>
```

css:

```
    .ul-unactive{
  max-height:0;
  transition: .5s;
  width:100%;

}
.ul-active{
  max-height:500px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
  width:100%;

}
```

Comment: Please also add the relevant HTML code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest()` won't work as your submenu is not a parent of the arrow toggle element.

Try using:

`$(this).closest('li').find('.ul-unactive').toggleClass('ul-active');`

Which searches *UP* the DOM tree for the closest `<li>` parent, then searches *DOWN* the DOM tree from there to find your `.ul-unactive` element.